# use a string or stream?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I need to progressively build a string and am trying to find the best way to do it. The maximum it can grow to is about 10k and hence was planning to do something like this:

```
const unsigned long long configSize = 10240; //Approximation
void makeMyConfig() {
   std::string resp;
   std::string input;
   resp.reserve(configSize);
   while ( getInput(input) ) {
     resp += input;
   }

   if ( resp.length > configSize ) 
      log << "May need to adjust configSize. Validate" << endl;

   if (!sendConfig(resp)){
      log << "Error sending config" << endl;
   }
}
```

`getInput` may read from file/tcp conn or ftp and is decided at runtime. It receives const char* and puts it into a string (which I may be able to avoid but left it for convenience)

However, I heard there is a much efficient way of doing with string streams but not sure how to do. Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Don't forget the parentheses on your `length` call: `if ( resp.length() > configSize )`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks pretty great to me.

- You're pre-allocating the buffer, avoiding ongoing allocations and copies.
- You already have it implemented

Don't optimize until you actually have a performance problem and can measure any performance changes. You might end up making it worse without realizing!

Comment: +1: I was starting to put together a solution using `stringstream` and it turned out to be much more verbose, with no recognizable benefit.

Comment: +1 for advice on not over-thinking this.  Even the solution in the question could be overkill, maybe just let `string` handle the memory unless strings tend to be on the large end of the spectrum.

Comment: Thanks, I will stick to the current one!

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Using `ostringstream` is only an advantage if much of the text is a result of formatting; e.g. from `int`s or `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the difference between reserving and not reserving a string, consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int BIG = 10000000;
const int EXTRA = 100;

int main() {

    string s1;
    s1.reserve( BIG );

    clock_t t = clock();
    for ( int i = 0; i < BIG + EXTRA; i++ ) {
        s1 += 'x';
    }
    cout << clock() - t << endl;

    string s2;
    t = clock();
    for ( int i = 0; i < BIG + EXTRA; i++ ) {
        s2 += 'x';
    }
    cout << clock() - t << endl;
}
```

In the first case, the string is reserved, in the second not. This produces the timings:

```
60
78
```

for g++ compiled with -O2.

Comment: What about if you reserve `BIG+EXTRA`, i.e. enough space?

Comment: @Steve I get 58 78 (or thereabouts), but  I was trying to simulate the OP's problem, where he doesn't know exactly how big the input is.

Comment: Interesting to know that it doesn't matter whether the estimate is truly an upper bound, then.